# Compare two excel sheets with differing shape and store the differences with the appropriate column headers in a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, difference

I have two excel worksheets which needs to be compared. Both the excel sheets have differing number of rows and columns and could have different column headers as well. I need to compare these two excel files and store the differences in a dataframe with the appropriate column headers. The following is an example of a sample data frame:

```
df1 = {a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
       b: [3, 5, 4, 23, 5, 8]
       c: [11, 26, 28, 32, 56, 21]
       d: [ 4, 65, 81, 93, 45, 34]}

df2 = {a: [1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6]
       b1: [3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 8]}
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't solve the purpose

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('excel1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('excel2.xlsx')

difference = df1[df1!=df2]

print(difference)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the differences ? columns ? rows ?

Comment: The differences could be new columns/rows, data updated in existing rows/columns or just the change in column headers

Answer (score 0):

If you using excel try to use append method it will append all the date which is has the same name of columns;

---

```
df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).